# Group Theory: Isomorphisms

Tags: group-theory

Let $H$ be a subgroup of the group $G$.

Claim: $S=\{aHa^{-1} : a \in G\} \cong H$.

My sketch: Define $\phi : S \to H$ by $aha^{-1} \mapsto h$. For injectivity, suppose $\phi(x) = \phi(y)$. By definition of being in the preimage, $x,y$ are of the form $bh_1b^{-1}$ and $ah_2a^{-1}$ respectively. Thus, $\phi(x)=\phi(y) \Rightarrow h_1 = h_2$ ??.

Question: Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong?

Edit: I will take the map to go from $H \to aHa^{-1}$ which is much easier to show. Thank you.

Comment: Indeed. A left coset is a group if and only if it is the left coset containing the identity.

Comment: Well I still run into the same problem. I made an edite above @MattS.

Comment: I think I should have $h_1,h_2$.

Comment: I think this is only true if $h = e$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For injectivity, you assume you have an equation

$$axa^{-1}=aya^{-1}$$

and you want to show that $x=y$.

For surjectivity, you want to show that for any element y in $H$ there is an element $x\in H$ such that $axa^{-1}=y$.

Comment: It looks like in you injectivity argument you are taking the map $H \to aHa^{-1}$. Am I correct?

Comment: I understand now thought. But the map you have is the reverse of mine which is probably easier.

Comment: I phrased it so it actually coincides with your map. The two approaches are very similar in any case.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't know how I missed that. Your exactly right. Thanks a lot. I'm embarrassed that i overlooked that. BUt now I know.

Comment: Sorry, I actually had it going both ways. I edited it to make it consistent with what I agree is the easier map, $x\mapsto axa^{-1}$.

Comment: I got what you were trying to say. Thanks.

Comment: I was confusing the fact that an element in $aHa^{-1}$ means it is conjugate to something in $G$, but instead i was thinking it had the form $x=aha^{-1}$.